# PHP coding: cannot find why it does not work

Tags: php, database

I am writing a program that is supposed to add a studio. This is my addstudio.php

```
<?php
include ("db.php");

$pagename="Add a New Location";
echo "<title>".$pagename."</title>";
echo "<h2>".$pagename."</h2>";

echo "<body>";
echo "<hr><b>".date('d F Y H:i:s')."</b>";
echo "<hr>Fill the form below to add a new studio";

//create a html form to capture user input
echo "<form method=post action=getstudio.php>" ;
echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=10>";

echo "<tr><td>*Studio Id </td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=form_studioID size=35></td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td>*Studio Name </td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=form_studioName size=35></td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td>*Address </td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=form_studioAddress size=35></td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td>*Post Code </td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=form_postcode size=35></td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td>Telephone Number </td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=form_tel size=35></td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td><input type=submit value='Add Studio'></td>";
echo "<td><input type=reset value='Clear Form'></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>" ;

echo "</body>";
?>
```

And then the getstudio.php file that is supposed to add the entered studio to the database and display all of them(the one that has been just entered and these that already were on the server)

```
<?php
include ("db.php");

$pagename="View Studio";
echo "<title>".$pagename."</title>";
echo "<h2>".$pagename."</h2>";

echo "<body>";
echo "<hr><b>".date('d F Y H:i:s')."</b>";
echo"<hr>";

//capture the values inserted in the form's fields and store them in local variables
$studid=$_POST['form_studioID'];
$studname=$_POST['form_studioName'];
$studaddress=$_POST['form_studioAddress'];
$studpostcode=$_POST['form_postoce'];
$studtel=$_POST['form_tel'];

//check if any if the mandatory fields were not filled in
if(empty($studid) or empty($studname) or empty($studaddress) or empty($studpostoce) 
  or empty($studtel)){
 echo "<p> Please ensure all fields are filled in !";   
}
else{
 $addstudioSQL=
     "insert into
     studio(studio_id, studio_name, studio_address, studio_postcode, studio_tel)
     values(".$studid.", '".$studname."', '".$studaddress."', '".$studpostcode."', '".$studtel."')";
}
    $exeaddstudioSQL=mysql_query($addstudioSQL);


//write SQL query
$viewstudioSQL="select studio_id, studio_name, studio_address, studio_postcode, studio_tel
            from studio
            order by studio_id";

//Run SQL query or exit if any errors are retrieved
$exeviewstudioSQL=mysql_query($viewstudioSQL) or die (mysql_error());

//Create an array of records and fecth the results of the execution of the SQL query
//Loop through the array of records and display details in specific format
while ($arraystudio=mysql_fetch_array($exeviewstudioSQL))
{
    echo "<p>Location Id: ".$arraystudio['studio_id'];
    echo "<br>".$arraystudio['studio_name']."<br> ".$arraystudio['studio_address'].", ".$arraystudio['studio_postcode'];
    echo "<br>".$arraystudio['studio_tel'];
    echo "<hr>";
}

echo "</body>";
?>
```

What this does is to print the studios that are on the server but not the one that has been just entered. It also has some problems with printing the postcode.
Anyone who can help? Much appreciated.

Comment: Test everything with `error_report(E_ALL)` and show the error here.

Comment: But the studio is correctly stored in the db? What does `$exeaddstudioSQL=mysql_query($addstudioSQL);` return?

Comment: Several notes: Your method and action should be enclosed in quotes. Stop using mysql_* functions, as they are removed in PHP7, and deprecated in previous versions, and they leave you extremely vulnerable to SQL injection and quoting issues. Instead, switch to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), and take advantage of prepared statements and parameter binding.

Comment: Martin Cup, isn't it just runs the $addstudioSQL, so it is insert the values into the DBMS? I mean, it should work, I think the problem is somewhere in my code as when I try to print a confirmation page taking the values from the server, works properly.

` if (mysql_errno($conn)==0)
 { 
  echo "<p>A new studio has been added successfully";
  echo "<p>Added studio id: ".$studid;
  echo "<br>Name: ".$studname;
  echo "<br>Address: ".$studaddress;
  echo "<br>Postcode: ".$studpostcode;
  echo "<br>Telephone number: ".$studtel;
 }`

Comment: Typo at: `$studpostcode=$_POST['form_postoce'];` and `empty($studpostoce)`

Comment: Yeah, this definitely does fix the problem why the postcode does not apear... Thanks a lot, I am looking at this code more than a week and I just get stuck, still can't make the typed studio to apper in the getstudio.php page